# PROC SQL equivalent of data step merge using IN

Tags: sas

I have to merge two very large files and I want to avoid this doing in Data step as that would mean sorting the data.  I need all observations for all IDs from left file excluding IDs that are not in the second.

```
data leftdata;
input id $ y;
datalines;
AA 10 
AA 20
BB 30
BB 40
CC 50
CC 80
DD 60
;run;

data rightdata;
input id $ ;
datalines;
AA  
BB
;
run;

*Using datastep;
PROC SORT DATA=leftdata; BY id; 
PROC SORT DATA=rightdata; BY id; RUN;
DATA datastep; 
MERGE leftdata(IN=a) rightdata(IN=b); 
BY id;  IF a and b=0; 
RUN;
```

How can the same be achieved using PROC SQL?

Final output must include the following observations:

```
CC 50
CC 80
DD 60
```

Comment: JOIN types are one way, in this case a left join is what you're looking for I believe. A right join would keep the data in the right data set.

Comment: Note that `PROC SQL` doesn't necessarily avoid sorting - joins may still involve sorting, you just don't get to control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways:

- `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT ...)` filtering, or
- `LEFT JOIN` where missing the right id.

Example:

```
data have;
input id $ y;
datalines;
AA 10 
AA 20
BB 30
BB 40
CC 50
CC 80
DD 60
;

data excluded_ids;
input id $ ;
datalines;
AA  
BB
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * from have
  where id not in (select id from excluded_ids)
  ;

  create table want as
  select have.* from have
  left join excluded_ids as remove
  on have.id = remove.id
  where remove.id is null
  ;
```

For the second way you will need a `SELECT DISTINCT` if the exclusion list has a repeated id.

---

**Data step**

Use a hash object to store the exclusion list and `check` method to test for *removal*

Example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash exclude(dataset:'excluded_ids');
    exclude.defineKey('id');
    exclude.defineDone();
  end;

  if exclude.check() = 0 then delete;
run;
```